# jQuery is not defined using jQuery and jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Realizing this question has been asked a million times, I can't find a solution that works for me.

Importing jQuery and jQuery UI using...

```
// Import libraries
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';

// DOM Ready
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log('DOM ready');
    const availableTags = ['ActionScript', 'AppleScript', 'Asp', 'BASIC', 'C', 'C++', 'Clojure', 'COBOL', 'ColdFusion', 'Erlang', 'Fortran', 'Groovy', 'Haskell', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'Lisp', 'Perl', 'PHP', 'Python', 'Ruby', 'Scala', 'Scheme'];
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
    });
});
```

I get an error that `jQuery is not defined` in `widget.js:24`

Typically, it seems to mean that jQuery isn't loading before it's being called? But I don't understand how to order the import calls in my case. Thx.

Comment: What framework or library are you using?

Comment: No framework. Just using Gulp/Babel to generate contents of my `dist` directory. Currently only importing jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: When you examine the Source of your output, do you see the proper libraries constructed in the `<head>` for both?

Comment: Maybe also try `jQuery(($) => { })` style code for testing. There may be a NameSpace conflict.

Comment: Gulp/Babel concat my code into one js file called `scripts.min.js` whose contents seem to contain the full jQuery and jQuery UI libraries. An aside, when I comment out the `import 'jquery-ui';` the error goes away. jQuery doesn't seem to be making it down into jquery-UI. I've also tried downloading and using `import './jquery-ui.min';` versus `npm install -save jquery-ui` and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working without any framework, just call the jquery script in the head-tag of your html file:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Web Page</title>
  <!-- Call the jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
 
    $(document).ready(function() {  
     ...
     ...
     ...
    })
   </script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**ALTERNATIVELY, using Gulp+Babel**:

Create a Gulpfile named gulpfile.js in your project's root directory, adapt it according to your own project structure (sub-directories):

```js
    const gulp = require('gulp');
    const concat = require('gulp-concat');
    const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

    gulp.task('scripts', () =>
      gulp
        .src(['node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'src/js/*.js']) 
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js')) 
        .pipe(uglify()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js')) 
    );

    
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series('scripts'));
```

Check the update of the source file (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js and 'src/js/*.js') and the destination folder (dist/js).

Add a `<script>` tag inside the head of your HTML file to include the processed JavaScript file (bundle.js) generated by Gulp:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Web Page</title>
  <!-- Include your processed JavaScript file -->
  <script src="dist/js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  ...
</body>
</html>
```